# Feature importance/ selection per class. How?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I followed this [scikit learn guidance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#tree-based-feature-selection) to find feature importance for a classification problem. Here's the code from the link:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X.shape

clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=50)
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
clf.feature_importances_
```

The problem is that, it's not actually what I really want. What I'd like to do is to discover feature importance per class.

One idea that comes to my mind is to turn the data into a binary classification, per class and to train a DecisionTree per class.

Is that a good approach? What are common ideas to deal with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one-vs-all classification is a common way of dealing with that issue. You could take that approach. While I don't think there is a principled way of obtaining class-specific feature importance for random forests, you could use the [SHAP package](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/text_examples/sentiment_analysis/Emotion%20classification%20multiclass%20example.html#Visualize-the-impact-on-a-single-class) to get Shapley values empirically.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, I don't have to stick to trees. So in general, which approach would you take?

Comment: If Logistic Regression can solve your problem, you will have access to the coefficient matrix `coef_`, which will tell you both an approximate class-specific feature importance (and whether they positively or negatively influence the decision.) Otherwise, I would suggest using SHAP.